# How SAX parser works?

Tags: java, xml, dom, sax

I'm new to XML Parsing. While doing one task where I need to parse Big XML file. So while trying to make a good solution I came across these two terms, DOM and SAX. These both are two different types of XML parsing. I'm here little confused in SAX parsing. Read about alot but still confused.

Lets take below XML's as an example

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
     <Desc>
       <to>Tove</to>
       <from>Jani</from>
       <heading>Reminder</heading>
       <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
     </Desc>
     <Desc>
       <to>Tove</to>
       <from>Jani</from>
       <heading>Reminder</heading>
       <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
     </Desc>
     <Desc>
       <to>Tove</to>
       <from>Jani</from>
       <heading>Reminder</heading>
       <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
     </Desc>
</note>
```

Lets say, I just want all read all `<body>` tags and write into file.

My Doubts:

1. If I do it with DOM parser, Will it load all xml first into memory and then look for `<body>` tag and write into a file ?
2. If I do it with SAX parser, Will it look for `<body>` tag itself on disk first, and the moment it finds it then it start reading from there and keep loading into memory until `</body>`  ?
3. If 2 doubt is correct, then how this kind of reading happens ? Does SAX parser reads word by word and keeps that word in a memory for a while and checks whether matches with the tag the code is looking for ? Because identification of tag can be done in memory only but nowhere that's what I think. And keep drooping the words from memory until it finds the selected match or tag `<body>`. The moment it finds it, It starts keeping all words in memory afterwards until it finds `</body>`.

Is it CORRECT?
Please correct me..!

Answer (score 4):

StAX (or pull parsers) will work better for the use-case you describe.
DOM reads the whole document, SAX parsers generate events that you need to handle, they don't store anything in memory (except their internals). With SAX you need to implement a content handler with [certain methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html) and this also implies that you need to maintain the state of the event stream. For example, the first chunk of the document you posted will generate the following (simplified) events:

```
startDocument
startElement(note)
startElement(Desc)
startElement(to)
characters(Tove) // might come as multiple chunks
endElement(to)
...
endDocument
```

so you need to check in startElement if the tag name is `body` (if you want only `body` elements that are in `note -> Desc` then you need keep track of all start/end elements) and set a flag. In `characters`, if the flag is true, collect the tag text content (or write it to disk). Also, in `endElement` the flag needs to be set to false to avoid collecting characters from other tags.

Answer (score 1):

The DOM parser loads the entire XML document into memory and makes it available to you through a Java API. The advantage of this approach is that it's simple to use and understand, but it's not very efficient, because:

- The parser has to read the entire XML document and store it in memory, even if you only want to access a small part of it.
- The data structures that the DOM parser uses (hash maps, most likely) are general-purpose and not optimized for your situation.

The SAX parser is harder to use but it potentially more performant. The SAX parser stores nothing in memory; instead, it invokes code you provide to handle each XML element it encounters. In your case, it will call you back saying "I found <note>!" then "I found <Desc>!" etc. What you do with these events is up to you, but generally you will either build some custom Java objects in memory, or generate a stream of output.

Comment: when you say " it will call you back saying "I found <note>!" then "I found <Desc>!", Where does it evaluates this ? While parsing, reading will be done from DISK and it must be evaluating "I found" something in Memory itself..Isn't ?

Comment: Assuming you're reading from disk, yes, the XML will be on disk, and the callback will be in memory. But the SAX parser will only keep the information about the element it's currently reading in memory. Once it passes that information to your program, the parser forgets about it. (Okay, it has to keep some extra information in memory in order to keep track of where it is in the document, but it's very little overhead.)

Comment: Think about it this way. You can write a DOM parser yourself using the SAX parser, by building a DOM structure from the events the SAX parser sends to you. But it wouldn't make sense to build a SAX parser using the DOM parser. The DOM parser is a higher level component.